# How would you read a csv in a stored procedure such that the csv needs data extraction?

Tags: postgresql, csv, stored-procedures

The csv has urls of images in the format -

```
www.domain.com/table_id/x_y_height_width.jpg
```

We want to extract table_id, x, y, height and width from these urls in a stored procedure and then use these parameters in multiple sql queries.

How can we do that?

Comment: You can use a foreign data wrapper to read the csv as a table. The rest of the question has been answered below. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[regexp_split_to_array and split_part functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

```
create or replace function split_url (
    _url text, out table_id int, out x int, out y int, out height int, out width int
) as $$
    select
        a[2]::int,
        split_part(a[3], '_', 1)::int,
        split_part(a[3], '_', 2)::int,
        split_part(a[3], '_', 3)::int,
        split_part(split_part(a[3], '_', 4), '.', 1)::int
    from (values
        (regexp_split_to_array(_url, '/'))
    ) rsa(a);
$$ language sql immutable;

select *
from split_url('www.domain.com/234/34_12_400_300.jpg');
 table_id | x  | y  | height | width 
----------+----+----+--------+-------
      234 | 34 | 12 |    400 |   300
```

To use the function with other tables do [`lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

```
with t (url) as ( values
    ('www.domain.com/234/34_12_400_300.jpg'),
    ('www.examplo.com/984/12_90_250_360.jpg')
)
select *
from
    t
    cross join lateral
    split_url(url)
;
                  url                  | table_id | x  | y  | height | width 
---------------------------------------+----------+----+----+--------+-------
 www.domain.com/234/34_12_400_300.jpg  |      234 | 34 | 12 |    400 |   300
 www.examplo.com/984/12_90_250_360.jpg |      984 | 12 | 90 |    250 |   360
```

Comment: This was really helpful!! Thanks!